# How to get a specific output if a value is within a range

Tags: excel, excel-formula

I have a range of multiple zip codes "boundaries" with a specific cost attached to it.

[image: Excel table]

I have a seperate file which indicates a zipcode. I have to use a formula which checks the table presented in the image, which checks in which zip code interval it belongs and then as a output gives the corresponding price.

In case of zip code 1234 it should give 300 as the output.
In case of zip code 2169 it should give 209 as the output.

I struggled with if functions (bigger than, smaller than, but couldn't get it to check the entire data file).

Comment: Shouldn't 1269 be 300?

Comment: sorry yes meant 2169

Answer (score 2):

I'm guessing, that's what you're looking for:
`=SUMPRODUCT((F$2:F$5)*(E$2:E$5<=H3)*(D$2:D$5>H3))`
[image]

Answer (score 1):

You can use `=VLOOKUP` or `=SUMIFS()` formula:

```
=VLOOKUP(1234,$A$2:$C$5,3,TRUE)
```

You need to set range_lookup TRUE (which is done in the code above).

Note that when the input value is lower than the minimum of the zipcode min it returns #N/A. When the input value is higher than all zipcode max it returns the value of maximum of zipcodes. You can fix those with `=IFNA` and `=IF` functions.

Use of `=SUMIFS()` where E2 is the input:

```
=SUMIFS($C$2:$C$5,$A$2:$A$5,"<="&E2,$B$2:$B$5,">="&E2)
```

Comment: I believe, you should read the question again - OP is requesting for lookup formula which returns not **exact** match (as `vlookup()` does), but match, based on range of values, which it falls in.

Comment: Also, in my opinion, VLOOKUP should NEVER be used. INDEX/MATCH can do everything VLOOKUP can. Plus, it is more efficient (faster), more versatile, and does not break if columns are inserted into the range.

Comment: @VasylZebra when you set `range_lookup = FALSE` you get exact match. When you set `range_lookup = TRUE` you get match based on range of values. `range_lookup` is the last input of `=VLOOKUP()`.

Comment: Thanks Mehmet your answer helped me out!

Comment: @Mehmet Yusuf Cakmak: I must admit, it does the job for this particular case - I, probably, haven't been using `vlookup()` for a while, mostly because of the reasons, stated above by @Gravitate - it's not flexible, sensitive to columns order, fails to cope with complex multiple criteria look-ups

Comment: @Mehmet Yusuf Cakmak: Let me join to the comments above - even though your solution works for this specific case, it will fail immediately as you have 'uncomfortable' column order, or some other columns in between, even `sumifs()` would be much better choice

Answer (score 1):

You could use an INDEX/MATCH:

[image]

```
=IFERROR(INDEX($C$3:$C$7,MATCH($F3,$A$3:$A$7,1)),"Not Found")
```

The match formula:

```
MATCH($F3,$A$3:$A$7,1)
```

Returns the index of the first zip which is less than the one specified.

The INDEX formula returns the value of the cell which has the same index, but in our "Price" range.

The IFERROR wrapper just outputs "Not found" instead of an error.

You will notice that this way, your "Zip Max" column is not really needed.
Any Zip below the Min will return an error anyway. And I have added a zip code to the list to ensure that anything greater returns "=NA()".